# azure-functions-maven-plugin issue: please downgrade the project compile version and try again

Tags: azure-functions, azure-java-tools

I am getting the next issue after running:

```
$ mvn azure-functions:deploy
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.9.0:deploy (default-cli) on project helidon-examples-microprofile-azure-functions: Your function app artifact compile version is higher than the java version in function host, please downgrade the project compile version and try again. -> [Help 1]
```

I don't know what does it mean that function host. It suggests to downgrade the compile version (that is currently jdk 11), but I cannot downgrade it because my applications depends on Helidon, and that is supported for JDK 11.

These are the generated files after running mvn package. The lib contains dependencies.

```
$ ls target/azure-functions/function2-helidon-azure/
helidon-examples-microprofile-azure-functions.jar  host.json  lib  local.settings.json  toUpperCase
```

This is the java version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 20.4-(Zulu-11.39+15-linux_x64)-Microsoft-Azure-restricted (build 11.0.7+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 20.4-(Zulu-11.39+15-linux_x64)-Microsoft-Azure-restricted (build 11.0.7+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

These are the JSON files:

```
host.json
{
    "functionTimeout": "00:09:00",
    "version": "3.0"
}

local.settings.json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
    }
}
```

And the pom.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.helidon.applications</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-mp</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../../applications/mp/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <functionAppName>function2-helidon-azure</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>westus</functionAppRegion>
        <functionResourceGroup>java-function-group</functionResourceGroup>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.9.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.4.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        
    </properties>
    
    <artifactId>helidon-examples-microprofile-azure-functions</artifactId>
    <name>Helidon Microprofile Examples Azure Functions</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.helidon.microprofile.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>helidon-microprofile-cloud-azure-functions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>obj/**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>extensions.csproj</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
                    <appSettings>
                        <!-- Run Azure Function from package file by default -->
                        <property>
                           <name>WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE</name>
                           <value>1</value>
                       </property>
                       <property>
                           <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                           <value>~3</value>
                       </property>
                       <property>
                           <name>FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME</name>
                           <value>java</value>
                       </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${stagingDirectory}
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/azure
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Though Java 11 support in Function is in preview currently, but it should work normally as I tested. I see in your POM.xml you are using `spring-cloud-function-dependencies` with version `3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`. Is that a stable build? I see latest stable is `3.0.10.RELEASE` at this moment  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-function-dependencies

Comment: I have edited my pom removing that spring dependency. My pom was copy-pasted from an Spring example, but this project is not related to Spring at all. Still same error occurs.

Comment: I now see duplicate entry of `azure-functions-java-library` in dependencies. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also wondering, from where `helidon-microprofile-cloud-azure-functions` comes from? I could not find it in public maven repo!

Comment: Yes that is another typo, I have fixed it. helidon-microprofile-cloud-azure-functions doesn't exist yet because it is a new module to be integrated in Helidon, but it exists in maven local repository. Find here the details:
https://github.com/oracle/helidon/pull/2365

Comment: Is the user @jbescos yourself? :) I was wondering at the comment https://github.com/oracle/helidon/pull/2365#issuecomment-698961345

Comment: I cannot comment on that :)

Comment: So my suspect is on `helidon-microprofile-cloud-azure-functions` since it works otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222943/discussion-between-ravenskater-and-krishg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it following this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli?pivots=programming-language-java&tabs=bash%2Cbrowser

In azure-functions-maven-plugin I was missing the section under 'configuration':

```
<runtime>
    <os>linux</os>
    <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
</runtime>
```

Then there are other issues after that.

I solved adding in the section 'configuration' the next:

```
<appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
```

And also the value of property 'functionResourceGroup' was misspelled. The value is:

```
<functionResourceGroup>java-functions-group</functionResourceGroup>
```